# How to balance code duplication with being able to prevent unnecessary service calls

Tags: design, web-services

Apologies in advance if this is considered opinion based, but I wasn't sure where to ask it and was interested in learning if there were any definitive best practices.

Say an application calls a service from one location, but a requirement is that `a == 1`. You would want to perform the `a == 1` check in the service to be able to handle it gracefully because you should assume the calling code will perform no validations. **Should you also perform the `a == 1` check in the application before making the call?** The downside being you've now duplicated code, but the upside being you could prevent a service call from being made that didn't need to be.

Does the answer change if the service is called from 10 locations in the application? Is it dependent on the amount of code being duplicated compared to the amount of network traffic, or load time experienced by the user, being added?

Comment: If you are worried about code duplication write a shared module. If for some reason the API and the client are written in incompatible languages design a test system that can pass the same document to both implementations of the validation logic. At the very least this allows you to keep them reasonably in sync, and know where the differences are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no clean answer for this predicament, particularly when you are talking about UI code that is separate from the server code.  It is very common to require those checks on both sides for the purpose of ensuring security.

**Why do the checks in the UI?**

- Helps provide feedback immediately to ensure the request is correct before it is ever sent
- Minimizes network traffic from well behaved clients

**Why do the checks in the API?**

- Not all clients are well behaved
- Protects against bad people who attempt to abuse your API to do what the UI won't allow

**When things get messy**

Most of the time, those double-checks are OK and reasonably justifiable.  Unfortunately, it is pretty easy to get into a place where one API call can generate 30-70 calls in a microservice infrastructure.  Typically it happens when you are not paying attention to how one service calls another, which in turn calls another.  Logs are very useful to follow what is happening on any given request.

In situations like that, sometimes it is useful to have a layer handle the requests on your behalf and perform some intelligent caching.  For example [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) will reduce the requests to microservices to just what is necessary to get your information.

Getting out of a mess requires:

- Understanding where the extra calls are coming from
- Understanding what in your architecture is encouraging duplicate calls
- Removing naive calls to get data you don't need
- Changing the design of your API or implementation that is causing the chain of requests

Nothing is a silver bullet (including GraphQL or caching).  Unnecessary service calls happen because your services are requesting data they may have already received.  Many times it is to support data calls that the user isn't even interested right now.  The answer to my project most likely won't be the answer to your project.